# PHP how to list out all public functions of class

Tags: php, class

I've heard of `get_class_methods()` but is there a way in PHP to gather an array of all of the public methods from a particular class?

Comment: Uhm, `get_class_methods($class)` *is* a way to gather an array of all public methods of a particular class...

Comment: if you want to use `get_class_methods` to retrieve ONLY public methods, it must used outside class..

Comment: get_class_methods($class) returns all methods which are either public or do not have a key word. So any private methods will not be returned

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes you can, take a look at the reflection classes / methods.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php and 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Apple');
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
var_dump($methods);
```

Comment: i am digging the simplicity that is caused by using the statics rather than going through the instantiation of Reflectionmethod

Comment: Not the right solution: You get also the static functions.

Answer (score 24):

As [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/get_class_methods) is scope-sensitive, you can get all the public methods of a class just by calling the function from outside the class' scope:

So, take this class:

```
class Foo {
    private function bar() {
        var_dump(get_class_methods($this));
    }

    public function baz() {}

    public function __construct() {
        $this->bar();
    }
}
```

`var_dump(get_class_methods('Foo'));` will output the following:

```
array
  0 => string 'baz' (length=3)
  1 => string '__construct' (length=11)
```

While a call from inside the scope of the class (`new Foo;`) would return:

```
array
  0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
  1 => string 'baz' (length=3)
  2 => string '__construct' (length=11)
```

Answer (score 10):

After getting all the methods with `get_class_methods($theClass)` you can loop through them with something like this:

```
foreach ($methods as $method) {
    $reflect = new ReflectionMethod($theClass, $method);
    if ($reflect->isPublic()) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit of an ugly one-liner to complement your approach: `array_filter(get_class_methods($this), function($v) { return (new ReflectionMethod($this, $v))->isPublic(); });`

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this way?

```
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new myclass());

foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}
```

Comment: I think Kristian is asking specifically for listing the public methods.